# Custom Taxonomy Term Caching?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, customization, terms

I have two Custom Post Types, "event", and "opportunity". They share a custom hierarchal taxonomy, "location". My client had added a handful of terms (United States (parent), then a few States (children)). I decided to save them time by adding the rest of the States via wp_insert_term.

This worked great! Or, so it seemed.

The terms showed up fine for me as an admin.

When logging into a "Contributor" account, I can go and create a new "Opportunity", and all the terms show as expected. When going to create a new "Event", the only terms that show up are the ones that were created by hand. You can *add* a new term on the spot via "Event" and it shows up just fine in the location manager.

Its as if WordPress is caching the older terms.

Any ideas what might be causing this or where I should look?

Details:

WordPress 3.0.3
Role Scoper 1.3.20

Comment: This other questions likely related worked for us:

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8357/inserting-terms-in-an-hierarchical-taxonomy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some bugs related to hierarchical term caching, indeed:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14704

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14485

Comment: Any suggestions for clearing the cache? Reviewing the tickets now.

Comment: Thanks for the references, Scribu. It turned out that it was caching - Its been awhile since I resolved this. Some action of mine with the terms forced it to reset.