# wp_insert_term - parent & child problem

Tags: custom-taxonomy, customization, taxonomy

I have a car database that I want to import into Wordpress as taxonomies. The problem is I can't create 2 taxonomies at once (first is parent, last ones are childs of first).

```
$p = wp_insert_term("Acura", "classified-category", array("description" => "Acura"));
$c = wp_insert_term("Acura CL", "classified-category", array("parent" => $p["term_id"], "description" => "Acura CL"));
print_r($p);
print_r($c);
```

returns:

```
Array ( [term_id] => 13 [term_taxonomy_id] => 4720 ) 
Array ( [term_id] => 2589 [term_taxonomy_id] => 4721 )
```

But in Dashboard appears just parent category. The problem is similar to this one: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23125/create-two-categories-at-once-parent-child

Any idea ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is with the taxonomy cache.  You have to clear it after you insert the terms in order to see them.  I had the same issue, which someone answered for me [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8357/inserting-terms-in-an-hierarchical-taxonomy/8921#8921):

```
delete_option("classified-category_children");
```

Insert that after the term inserts and you should be good.

Comment: works great! thx!

Comment: Glad I was able to help out

Comment: Awesome. Worked perfectly.