# How to set hierarchical terms to a post using wp_set_object_terms

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, hierarchical, terms

I have a hierarchical custom taxonomy called "locations". The parent categories are country names, the child categories are the territories under the country.

How can i attach these terms to a post programatically?

```
$country = 'Egypt';
$territory = 'Hurghada';
```

So, if the Egypt category doesn't exist, i need to create it, and i need to attach the $territory in a subcategory under Egypt.

This is where i am so far:

```
$post_id = 10;

$country_term_id = term_exists( $country, 'locations' );

if ($country_term_id !== 0 && $country_term_id !== null) {
    wp_set_post_terms($id, $country,'locations');
} else {
    //I guess this is where i need to set the territory?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [`wp_set_post_terms()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_set_post_terms/) does not accept hierarchy for it, you will first have to check if terms exist already, create them using [`wp_insert_term()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_insert_term/) if not and only then assign to post.

Note that there had been (don't know current state) some cache related bugs with doing such things on the fly, see [Inserting terms in an Hierarchical Taxonomy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8357/inserting-terms-in-an-hierarchical-taxonomy)

Comment: Thanks, yes, i know understand the logic, i just need to check & create the subcategory with wp_insert_term, and i just attach the term by id to the post