# Custom Taxonomy: Parent still counting deleted Child

Tags: custom-taxonomy, get-children

I have this weird situation when I deleted two child taxonomies but they still seem to be assigned to their parent.

I need a overview site for all our products with the taxonomy title ahead. If there is a child taxonomy the products should display under the child, and not under the parent taxonomy.

**the code**

```
$args = array(
    'type'                     => 'anco_produkt',
    'orderby'                  => 'menu_order',
    'order'                    => 'ASC',
    'taxonomy'                 => 'produkt_category'
); 
$taxonomies = get_categories($args);

foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {
  if($taxonomy->parent == 0) {
    echo '<h3 class="alignnone">'.$taxonomy->name.'</h3>';
  } else {
    echo '<h4>'.$taxonomy->name.'</h4>';
  }

  // Get the children of current taxonomy
  $tax_children = get_term_children($taxonomy->term_id , 'produkt_category');

  if(count($tax_children) == 0) { // Are there children?
    // Do something with the posts
  }
```

It works great!

But I have a taxonomy with two former child-taxonomies. I deleted them and assigned all the affected posts to the parent category, but the posts don't show up under the parent category.

I tested if I get any children with:

```
print_r($tax_children);
echo count($tax_children);
```

And voilà, I get their IDs (19 and 22) and a count of 2 children for this "childrenless" parent. In the DB are no taxonomies/categories with these IDs. I tried `wp_delete_term()` and `wp_delete_category()`, this parent just can't let go of it's children :((

**the problem in action:**
http://ch-de.ancotech.com/produkte/

**the taxonomies**
[image: the taxonomies I currently use]

There should be 15 products under 'Spezialbewehrungen'...

Has someone a idea?

Ps. Should I send the parent to therapy to accept the loss of its children?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The problem

There's on (imho) serious issue with WordPress and Taxonomies and their term hierarchy (and children): They aren't really fetched from the actual state, but someone who thought (s)he might be really "smart" stuffed that into the `*_options` table.

Just take a look at the source of [`get_term_children()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_term_children/): It makes a call to  [`_get_term_hierarchy()`](http://queryposts.com/function/_get_term_hierarchy/). And in there the following is used to retrieve the children of a taxonomy:

```
get_option( "{$taxonomy}_children" )
```

Now it might sound smart at first to leverage a static array instead of a real count, but at the long term it's a maintenance nightmare. WordPress has to keep that value updated and in case someone forgets to trigger that update programmatically, it gets out of sync and fails.

### Real world example

To get a proof for that, you can do a plain DB call in (for e.g.) phpMyAdmin (or whatever you use): Just replace `{$wpdb->prefix}` with your DB table prefix.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `{$wpdb->prefix}_options` 
WHERE  `option_name` LIKE  '%children'
ORDER BY  `{$wpdb->prefix}_options`.`option_name` ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 1000
```

The result will be something like the following - a serialized array:

```
a:2:{i:23;a:5:{i:0;i:38;i:1;i:39;i:2;i:40;i:3;i:41;i:4;i:42;}i:40;a:1:{i:0;i:43;}}
```

Or when deserialized:

```
array (
  23 => 
  array (
    0 => 38,
    1 => 39,
    2 => 40,
    3 => 41,
    4 => 42,
  ),
  40 => 
  array (
    0 => 43,
  ),
)
```

So the keys are the parent terms, while the sub arrays are the associated child terms.

### What's wrong?

First off: I'm not completely sure about this, as WP uses plenty of plain functions and DB calls and tracing all routes is quite tough - maybe I got lost in some rabbit hole.

When I look at [`wp_delete_term()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.6.1/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L1763) it seems that there's nowhere an update of the actual option happening. And `wp_delete_category()` is just a wrapper for that. So in order to keep your children in sync, you'll have to ***manually*** update that option.

I've written an importer once, where I stumbled upon the same problem and had to update the option manually as well. So unless no one smarter than me enters the stage, I think this is the only way to go: [`update_option()`](http://queryposts.com/function/update_option/):

```
$taxonomy = 'your_current_taxonomy';
$children = get_option( "{$taxonomy}_children" );
// Merge here
update_option( "{$taxonomy}_children", $your_new_value );
```

#### EDIT (1)

One more thing for everyone who wants to reproduce that or get some proof: There's no way to ***actually see*** that the children are out of synch, ***unless*** you take a look at the taxonomy list table screen in admin or comparing the option return value manually. Everything else will just work as expected and look ok.

#### EDIT (2)

As @MannyFleurmond just commented, there might be another option: Deleting the option and let WP regenerate it for you. I searched core and looked into `wp_delete_term()` in `~/wp-includes/taxonomy.php`... and found something: [`clean_term_cache`](http://queryposts.com/function/clean_term_cache/)<sup>[Source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.6.1/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L2674)</sup> really has a part that does this:

```
    if ( $clean_taxonomy ) {
        wp_cache_delete('all_ids', $taxonomy);
        wp_cache_delete('get', $taxonomy);
        delete_option("{$taxonomy}_children");
        // Regenerate {$taxonomy}_children
        _get_term_hierarchy($taxonomy);
    }
```

Point still is, that it doesn't trigger. The reason is simple: The 3rd argument is `true` per default. And therefore - see [source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.6.1/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L2704) - it won't trigger an update.

A possible solution *might* be the following: Use a hook and clean it manually to  trigger an update:

```
// The last hook before everything happens in core:
do_action( 'deleted_term_taxonomy', $tt_id );
```

So we could use that:

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) OR exit;
/** Plugin Name: (#117373) Fix Child term relationships */

add_action( 'deleted_term_taxonomy', 'wpse117374UpdateTaxChildCount' );
function wpse117374UpdateTaxChildCount( $termID )
{
    $tax = get_current_screen()->taxonomy;
    delete_option( "{$tax}_children" );
    # OR: ... alternate solution
    // clear_term_cache( $termID, get_current_screen()->taxonomy, false );
}
```

Keep in mind that above plugin isn't tested. But if it works, please leave a comment so people can simply use this as mu-plugin to automatically fix this crap :)

Comment: If you delete the option, WordPress will recreate it the next time it calls for the Taxonomy.  Might be an alternate solution.

Comment: Ok, updated by @MannyFleurmond recommendation. Seems like this might be a fix. :) Thanks Manny!

Comment: What @MannyFleurmond said is absolutely true. I've deleted all `{$taxonomy}_children` option using a simple SQL query (and checked db if delete was successful). After that I login, visited *Dashboard -> Posts -> Categories* and just after page loaded the `category_children` option appear in db.

Comment: Got the info from a similar question I asked a while ago: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8357/inserting-terms-in-an-hierarchical-taxonomy .  Had the same problem of modifying a taxonomy and it not being reflected on the tax page.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information and solution! Because it had to be solved quick I followed @MannyFleurmonds solution by deleting the DB entries. Worked like a charm. When I get the time I will test the plugin in a save test environment and will report back for further use.

Comment: We had some discussion in chat with @G.M. - there might be an even better solution. If so, there shall be update.