# Adding Child Terms Programatically - No Warning but No dice either

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

Here's essentially what I'm doing :

```
create_taxonomy_record(array(
            'Label',
            'tax_parent_slug',
            'Label Related',
            'this_tax_term_slug'));
/* ---> Create a child */
            create_taxonomy_record(array(
            'Label 2',
            'this_tax_term_slug',
            'Label Related',
            'this_tax_term_slug_a_child'));
```

and here's that function named `create_taxonomy_record` (its very vanilla - echos are for debug purposes)

```
create_taxonomy_record($args)
        {

            $term = term_exists($args[0], $args[1]);
            if ($term == 0 || $term == null) {

                wp_insert_term(
                    $args[0], // the term
                    $args[1], // the taxonomy
                    array(
                        'description'=> $args[2],
                        'slug' => $args[3],
                        'parent'=> $args[1]
                        )
                );
            }
            else { echo "<h1>" . $args[0] . " exists in parent " . $args[1] ."</h1>";}
        }
```

So this isn't working but its also not hard failing. I have warnings / errors on and this code provides neither.

**What's Working:**

- All 1st tier terms in the taxonomy are registering fine(1->n, i've run tests against 10k calls to this function and all perform nominally)

**What's Not Working:**

- when I try to assign a child term to a parent term. I do not get a warning, failure or false match of existence, i just don't get anything.

**Now I did find this :**

[Inserting terms in an Hierarchical Taxonomy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8357/inserting-terms-in-an-hierarchical-taxonomy/8921#8921)

However this did not seem to fix the issue. Or rather perhaps I am going about the cache clear incorrectly.

What I tried for the cache clear looked something like this:

```
create_taxonomy_record(array(
                'Label',
                'tax_parent_slug',
                'Label Related',
                'this_tax_term_slug'));
    /* ---> Create a child */

/* Tried it here */
delete_option("this_tax_term_slug_children");
                create_taxonomy_record(array(
                'Label 2',
                'this_tax_term_slug',
                'Label Related',
                'this_tax_term_slug_a_child'));

/* and here - all permutations/ combinations should be considered attempted */
delete_option("this_tax_term_slug_children");
```

No dice.

Comment: Is the second code snippet a user function definition? If so, you left the word `function` off the beginning.

Comment: hey charles no - its the same call to the method. Delete_option is (from my understanding?) a WP function, if thats what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you use `wp_insert_term` function incorrectly. Please read the [codex manual page](http://codex.wordpress.org/wp_insert_term) carefully and you will see that the second argument is not parent slug, but your custom taxonomy.

So your function should look like this:

```
create_taxonomy_record($args) {
    $parent_term = 0;
    if (!empty($args[2]) && ($parent_term = term_exists($args[2], $args[1])) {
       $parent_term = $parent_term['term_id'];
    }

    $term = term_exists($args[0], $args[1]);
    if ($term == 0 || $term == null) {
        wp_insert_term(
            $args[0], // the term
            $args[1], // the taxonomy
            array(
                'parent'      => $parent_term,
                'description' => $args[3],
                'slug'        => $args[4],
            )
        );
    }

    else { echo "<h1>" . $args[0] . " exists in parent " . $args[1] ."</h1>";}
}
```

Pay attention to `$args` array, now it should has 5 elements:

1. Term
2. Taxonomy
3. Parent term slug
4. Description
5. Term slug

And you can use it like this:

```
create_taxonomy_record(array(
    'Label',
    'your_custom_taxonomy_name_has_to_be_here',
    0,
    'Label Related',
    'this_tax_term_slug',
));

/* ---> Create a child */

create_taxonomy_record(array(
    'Label 2',
    'your_custom_taxonomy_name_has_to_be_here',
    'this_tax_term_slug',
    'Label Related',
    'this_tax_term_slug_a_child'
));
```